# Can you use PEX for venting?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, pex

Is there such an option as using PEX for an 1-1/2 vent ? I have a stretch where I need some flexibility for my pipe which is going to be difficult to achieve with copper or ABS.

this is related to this question

[What fittings can I use to re-route my copper DWV pipe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201507/what-fittings-can-i-use-to-re-route-my-copper-dwv-pipe)

Comment: Check your locks code.  Some areas allow heat bending of pvc vent pipes

Comment: the PVC won't fit through that opening where I need it to be (remember where we discussed the 90 elbow I was looking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pex is only legal for supply plumbing. It's not rigid enough for drain or vent use, as the lack of internal pressure could result in it being constricted.